# Would it be possible to translate specific terms with regex

Tags: regex

I'm using the following software:

http://www.tntranslations.com/TermInjectorHelp.html#regexexample

Would it be possible to use regex and this program with an "if statement" function?

I.e. if \1 = red then display ROUGE, if \1 = blue then display BLUE?

(rouge|bleu|jaune)  \1 (where it would display the appropriate translation:red|blue|yellow) red|blue|yellow

My guess is it's not possible, but I thought I would ask. Thanks!

At the moment I can do the following:

la voiture rouge = the red car (saved in the db)

(rouge|bleu)    \1  red|blue

la voiture bleu = the bleu car (suggested using the regex program)

I want to change "bleu" to "blue"

Comment: I would ask support for TermInjector, not StackOverflow

Comment: It's not supported by terminjector as a specific feature, so I thought I'd see if there was any way of using regex itself - as I said, I thought there probably wasn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this kind of task is done in a programming language, in a replacement function, using what is known as a lambda or delegate or anonymous function to perform the conditional replacement.

A straight regex replacement cannot inject text that is not already available in the text. So this is normally not possible in a non-programming environment, such as a text editor that supports regex (e.g. Notepad++, EditPadPro), and presumably in a tool like TermInjector (although I don't know its specs).

**Injecting Text that Isn't There: Regex Hack**

For completion, I'll mention a regex hack I sometimes use that would allow you to inject the translation using a text editor. For this, you would have to paste a small "dictionary" at the very bottom of the file: something like

```
##DIC##:bleu=blue:rouge=red:vert=green:jaune=yellow:brun=brown
```

Then a regex can be made that looks up the dictionary value, which is used in the replacement. For that to work, the engine must support lookarounds, which may not be the case with your tool.

Comment: That certainly sounds interesting. If you don't mind, I'd like to give it a go and see if it will work.

Comment: Okay then. First will you please find out if the syntax supports lookahead? If you search for this `(?=` and find it then the answer is yes.

Comment: The regex characters supported are listed on the page I provided a link to. Maybe the developer could also adapt the settings to be compatible with any hack you could think of, even if it didn't work immediately. Thanks for trying in any case.

Comment: I have this info: \S and \d are not supported, but they can be replaced by [^ ] and [0-9] respectively. The non-capturing group operator ?: is not supported either, TermInjector only captures the outermost parenthesis group.

So I assume (?= would not work...

Comment: I believe it uses POSIX regex

Comment: There's some more info about the program here: http://multifarious.filkin.com/2012/08/31/terminjector/

Comment: You're very welcome, thanks for the green checkmark. :)